# C++ UDP client problem

Tags: c++, networking, client, udp, wireless

I'm working on a reliable UDP based file sharing program. The program consists of 2 parts.
Server and Client.
Any client may request to download any file. When this occurs, the server should notify the client that owns the file to be downloaded that someone wants to download that file. The server should then somehow indicate to the client that is trying to download the file the IP and Port of the client that has the file.

The program is almost done. including the ACKing mechanism. But I have a problem that I couldn't solve for the last couple of hours. if I start the client part of the program on the same machine as my server, and open another instance of the client on another machine everything works perfectly fine. However if I open the server on one machine and open the client programs on different machines I can't send the file from one client to another. I don't know what could possibly cause this issue. I would be happy to send you the solution if you give me your e-mail I don't want to post 1000s of lines of code here.

EDIT:
OK. I tried every possible scenario and still no solution. I started to think about maybe the problem is not related with the program, maybe its related with my network connections.
The computer I'm using as a server is directly connected to the router using ethernet, but the other computers using wireless connection. I'm not sure if it makes a difference? I also tried running the server application on one of my wireless computers, but other computers couldn't connect to it. So it seems like the problem is related with the wireless network.

Comment: Offline help is discouraged on this Q&A forum, since it is intended to be of benefit to all visitors, not just the person who asked the question. You are more likely to get help if you can distil the problem to a small sample program that exhibits the problem. In doing so, you might even discover the bug yourself.

Comment: What Marcelo meant to say is that this website is *not* a forum.

Comment: @Cody: I meant "forum" in the classical (dictionary) sense of the word.

Comment: I would be really happy to explain the solution to the others with sample codes here once I find out what problem is. its really difficult to create a small sample program out of a complete solution. By doing that I may even miss the broken part.

Comment: @man camp: First of all get known what's going wrong, you haven't posted any details about this. Debug it or log it as `Nim` suggested.

Comment: I did everything that Nim suggested. Checked all the requests, IP's and Port's. Everything looks perfectly fine. Sender reads the file, grabs the first chunk according to the buffer size and sends it to the receiver, but for some reason the receiver never gets it. And I don't understand why it works when I open one client on the same machine as my server and the other client on another machine.

Comment: @man surely you can do better reporting than "can't send the file"! e.g.: do you receive packets at all?

Comment: What does `netstat` show? Maybe you are listening only on loopback... Also, do some `tcpdump`/`wireshark` to see what's going on on the network level

Answer (score 0):

hmm, without the details of your protocol, it's difficult to tell what the problem could be, however here are some suggestions:

1. In the protocol between server and client, check that the client requesting the file requests it correctly.
2. Next between the server and the second client, check that your protocol sends the correct request
3. Check that the second client generates the correct response (e.g I have file or I don't)
4. Check that the server processes this response correctly
5. Check that the server sends the correct ip address of the second client to the first
6. Check that the first client has network connectivity to the second client (say firewall etc.)
7. Check that the you processing logic in the client does process the response correctly.

Normally you should be able to do the above by putting in appropriate logging in the client/server code, and a simple telnet/ping etc. from first client to second.

Just moving something up from the comments... It's a tricky thing implementing a reliable protocol over UDP, however a good starting point is to assume that your code is broken and investigate (as in steps above) first...

Comment: Given that the protocol is implemented over UDP, there's a whole lot more that could be said.

Comment: @Marcelo, of course, but I didn't want to sit here all day writing about the difficulties of implementing a reliable protocol over UDP. With these types of problems, a good starting point is the assumption that your code is broken and investigate that first.

Comment: Agreed, and something like your response to my comment would make for a much better prologue than, "Can't say any more..."